# How to use CTE's for multiplication of columns

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to multiply column1 by column2; based on whether there is a value in column2. If there was a value in column2, then the answer will be put in column3. I am trying to use the WITH and a Common Table Expression.

I have searched through the forums, there seems to be no CTE questions similar to this one.

```
WITH cte_apfc AS(
    SELECT SUM(CAST("column1" AS numeric(4,2))) * SUM(CAST("column2" AS numeric(4,2)))
    FROM table1
    )

    UPDATE table1
    SET "column3" = cte_apfc
    FROM cte_apfc
    WHERE "column2" IS NOT NULL;
```

This is the error which I am currently receiving, and I am not sure how to fix it.

ERROR:  column "column3" is of type numeric but expression is of type record
LINE 13:  SET "column3" = cte_apfc
                                              ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

Comment: Why those casts to numeric? Aren't those columns defined as numeric or integer?

Comment: Thank you for questioning it - you helped me come to the right solution. It was so simple it blew my mind :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, I over complicated it. I did not need to use CAST as the columns were already numeric (thank you horse_with_no_name).

The solution was beyond simple...

```
UPDATE table1
SET "column3" = "column1" * "column2"
WHERE "column2" IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference the alias of the CTE, you need to reference the column. And for that you need to define a column alias:

```
WITH cte_apfc AS(
  SELECT SUM(CAST("column1" AS numeric(4,2))) * SUM(CAST("column2" AS numeric(4,2))) as value
  FROM table1
)
UPDATE table1
   SET "column3" = c.value
FROM cte_apfc c
WHERE "column2" IS NOT NULL;
```

You probably also want a `WHERE "column2" IS NOT NULL` inside the query that multiplies the values.

---

Note that you don't really need a CTE for that:

```
UPDATE table1
   SET "column3" = (SELECT SUM(CAST("column1" AS numeric(4,2))) * SUM(CAST("column2" AS numeric(4,2)))
                    FROM table1)
WHERE "column2" IS NOT NULL;
```